# Python - websocket data not sending without delay when inside if

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a code using rtmidi and websockets, which listenes for midi input and then sends data through websocket to all connected users. The data is beeing sent inside if statement, when some condition is met. In this test, the condition is simply random number comparison. Client can conenct to websocket server, however never receives any dat, even though server confirms that it was sent.
When I added asyncio.sleep(0) just before sending data, everything started working. Why is that? Should I use sleep, or is there a better solution?
I removed everything rtmidi related from example to make it easier, the problem is still the same.

Server code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import random

async def key(websocket, path):
    print("port connected ", path)
    while True:
        rnd=random.randrange(0,300000)
        if rnd==0:
            #await asyncio.sleep(0)  #when not commented everything works
            print("sent")
            await websocket.send("hello")

start_server = websockets.serve(key, "127.0.0.1", 8765)
print("done")
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Client code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def gdata():
    uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        
        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            print(data)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(gdata())
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your findings with Python 3.8 and websockets 8.1. Starting server and then client, the server prints "sent" and the client prints "hello" in irregular intervals averaging several times per second. The behavior does not appear to be affected by activating or deactivating the `await asyncio.sleep(0)` line.